# Can I develop Android apps without an IDE?

Tags: java, android, sdk

Is it possible to develop Android apps using only the Android SDK, without any IDE like Android Studio?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html

Comment: have you tried vs? [FREE community edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) ==> [Cross-Platform Development in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx) -- i've not tried it; just something you might wish to investigate.

Comment: it is possible with java sdk, so l guess is possible too for android sdk

Comment: Some time has passed since the original question and the most upvoted answer have been posted, e.g. the `android` tool is now obsolete. On another occasion I gave an overview about the current state of things (May 2023) in "Command-Line based Development Environments for Building and Debugging Android Applications" (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76150499/19980636) on desktop systems (Linux, Windows, MacOS) as well as on mobile (Android) in another SO thread on "How to make an Android app without using Android Studio".

Answer (score 27):

Yes, see [the Google SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html#CommandLine).

However, with the current toolchain and documentation it'll be an uphill struggle. I'm trying to do this too (for a dev who lives in Vim and Unix tools, Android Studio is needlessly slow and bloated).

The main issues I've found so far:

1. The [SDK documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html#CommandLine) gives instructions to create an Ant-driven project, but the SDK is now geared towards using Gradle. If you're working through the Google documentation in a linear fashion, you'll find subsequent lessons have you issue Gradle build instructions. For your Ant-built project.
2. There is very little documentation on how to actually create a Gradle-built project from the command line. The command line I use is:

   `android create project --target android-22 --name MyProjectName --path my_project/ --activity MyProject --package com.example.android.myproject --gradle --gradle-version 1.2.2`

   The `--gradle-version` actually refers to the Gradle Android plugin version, not the version of Gradle itself. Finding this out wasn't easy.
3. Even if you get it to create a project properly, it probably won't build without further manipulation. One of the generated files (`project/build.gradle`) has an invalid directive name (`runProguard` - I'm guessing it's now deprecated). That must be changed to `minifyEnabled` before the project will build. And using the Gradle plugin 1.2.2, the file `project/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` has the Gradle distribution incorrectly listed as `gradle-1.2.2-all.zip`. This should be `gradle-2.2.1-all.zip`.

   These are files generated by the SDK with errors.
4. The documentation is focussed on IDE-based development. Once you get past the initial few pages on creating and managing a project using the command line, it's very IDE-focussed.

   Instructions on things like changing an app Theme are difficult or impossible to follow as they omit steps that the IDE performs for you.

In general, fully IDE-less development for Android (at least in Java, using the official SDK) is very painful. And my personal opinion is that IDE-based development is equally painful (slow, bloated, ugly on high-DPI screens under Linux and evidently full of magic that's a pain to replicate on the command line).

*Edit: I should add that the above refers to using SDK tools v24.2, SDK Platform-tools v22, SDK Build-tools v22.01 and Android API 22 (5.1.1).*

Comment: You still need an IDE to design the UI part. Yes of course, you can use design UI in XML, but you still need a preview how it looks like. Java based IDEs are heavy and slow, but you still are better of using a Vi plugin like Vrapper for Eclipse or IdeaVim for Android Studio.

Comment: PLEASE for all of us following your intrepid footsteps, write a blog of your journey into the black and green.

Comment: @AndaluZ, you don't need to load a full integrated environment for just one UI editor.

Comment: Some time has passed, e.g. the `android` tool has become obsolete. So I tried to give an overview about the current, year 2023, state of things. It can be found in a post in another SO thread on "How to make an Android app without using Android Studio" -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/76150499/19980636

Answer (score 1):

Writing an Android app on Notepad is what I do on my Windows Laptop.

First you configure your laptop as follows:

1. **Download development Kits:** Download a Java Development Kit 1.6 for Windows and an Android Development Kit . Similarly try downloading older version of Android kit GUI version of Kit Manager so that you can download essentials. Using kit Manager download Android-23 platform build tools. Android Studio may have slower performance, so try to avoid it.
2. **Configure Kits:** Set Windows `PATH` variable by right clicking `My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings` or change the appropriate settings in your Control Panel. `PATH` should include the Java's compiler executable
   file in Java directory, and the `android.bat` file of Android Kit.
3. **Download Build-Tool:** (recommended, but Ant can be used too.) These
   programs configure the command-line tools for easy usage for our
   convenience. I downloaded version 2.2.1 as it can use old
   Java & old Android.

I've also written [about these instructions on my GitHub Page](https://web.archive.org/web/20201202190343/https://animeshshrivastav.github.io/).

Answer (score 1):

For the development of Android apps one doesn't even need a PC, and not even the Android SDK. One can develop them completely on a mobile Android device, so an emulator isn't necessary either.

For that, one needs the app [Termux](https://wiki.termux.com) on the device, and the [necessary APK building programs](https://timeout.userpage.fu-berlin.de/apk-builder/en/index.php) that come with the Termux packages `aapt`, `apksigner`, `clang`, `cmake`, `d8`, `ecj`, `kotlin`, `make` and `unzip`, including the OpenJDK and further dependencies. One can either stitch them together to an own toolchain, or use an existing one, e.g. [`zs-apk-builder`](https://timeout.userpage.fu-berlin.de/apk-builder/en/index.php#zs-apk-builder).

See also how to [collect the project dependencies](https://timeout.userpage.fu-berlin.de/dependency-harvesters/en/index.php). There are more light-weight approaches than using `gradle`.

---

***Edit***: Some time has passed since the original question and the most upvoted answer have been posted, e.g. the `android` tool is now obsolete. On another occasion I gave an overview about the current state of things (May 2023) in [Command-Line based Development Environments for Building and Debugging Android Applications](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76150499/19980636) on desktop systems (Linux, Windows, MacOS) as well as on mobile (Android) in another SO thread on "How to make an Android app without using Android Studio".

Answer (score 0):

For android the basic debugging environments are:
ADB
DDMS
Java Debugger

You can try with them. 
More details are here : http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects-cmdline.html

Comment: This does not address the question which was actually asked.