# android command is not in the tools directory

Tags: android

I downloaded from [this page](https://developer.android.com/studio) the file
`commandlinetools-linux-9477386_latest.zip` I can't find there the `android` command
for creating new projects from command line. I created a few small such projects about 10 years ago. Where is the `android` command now? It was in the `tools` directory before.

```
$ sdkmanager --list
[=======================================] 100% Computing updates...             
Installed packages:
  Path                 | Version | Description                | Location            
  -------              | ------- | -------                    | -------             
  build-tools;31.0.0   | 31.0.0  | Android SDK Build-Tools 31 | build-tools/31.0.0  
  platform-tools       | 34.0.1  | Android SDK Platform-Tools | platform-tools      
  platforms;android-31 | 1       | Android SDK Platform 31    | platforms/android-31
  sources;android-31   | 1       | Sources for Android 31     | sources/android-31  

$ tree -L 5 -d src/
src/
└── Android
    └── SDK
        ├── build-tools
        │   └── 31.0.0
        │       ├── lib
        │       ├── lib64
        │       ├── lld-bin
        │       └── renderscript
        ├── cmdline-tools
        │   ├── latest
        │   │   ├── bin
        │   │   └── lib
        │   └── tools
        │       ├── bin
        │       └── lib
        ├── licenses
        ├── platforms
        │   └── android-31
        │       ├── data
        │       ├── optional
        │       ├── skins
        │       └── templates
        ├── platform-tools
        │   └── lib64
        └── sources
            └── android-31
                ├── android
                ├── androidx
                ├── benchmarks
                ├── com
                ├── java
                ├── javax
                ├── jdk
                ├── jsr166
                ├── junit
                ├── mypackage
                ├── org
                ├── perftests
                └── tck
```

Comment: The tools you are searching are no longer compatible with recent Java versions (Java 9+). Finally they seem to be removed from Android SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The now obsolete `android` tool (for replacements per functionality see its [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/help/android)) is part of the likewise obsolete *Android SDK Tools* (replaced by [*Android SDK Command-line Tools*](https://developer.android.com/studio#command-line-tools-only), which you have downloaded).

Nevertheless, the site [androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com) mirrors everything related to the Android SDK from past and present, inter alia [downloads and installation guidance for the obsolete *Android SDK Tools*](https://androidsdkoffline.blogspot.com/p/android-sdk-tools.html).

In short -- To use the `android` tool you have to downgrade, so:

1. Remove your installation of the *Android SDK Command-line Tools*.
2. Install the (obsolete) *Android SDK Tools*.

---

**NB:** Don't mix up all the "Tools" packages, they all contain different stuff. The very first thing to install is either the old *Android SDK Tools* or the new *Android SDK Command-line Tools*. Only then one installs the *Build Tools* and the *Platform Tools*. For an overview see the Stackoverflow Post on ["Command-Line based Development Environments for Building and Debugging Android Applications"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76150499/19980636).

Answer (score 1):

Use the [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdkmanager) command line to install build tools and platform tools

Once it is completed add the `platform-tools` and `tools` directory to PATH

You can manually download [platform-tools](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools)

You can manually download [emulator](https://developer.android.com/studio/emulator_archive) also

In case `tools` is missing that means it is obsolete then you need to add `--include_obsolete`

you can install emulator like this `sdkmanager --channel=3 emulator` or `--channel=0` or `--channel=2` or `--channel=1` same applicable while installing `tools`

Example `sdkmanager --channel=3 tools --include_obsolete`

Another Example

```
./sdkmanager.bat --channel=3 tools --include_obsolete --verbose
```

You will get output like this

```
Info: Preparing "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)".
Info: "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" ready.
Info: Installing Android SDK Tools in C:\MyFiles\android-sdk-windows\tools
[=======================================] 100% Unzipping... tools/support/typos-
Info: "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" complete.
Info: "Install Android SDK Tools (revision: 26.1.1)" finished.
```

Comment: I have this error when writing `$ sdkmanager "tools"
Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!                         
Warning: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies. `

Comment: `$ sdkmanager "platform-tools"` works but `$ sdkmanager "tools"` doesn't work.

Comment: `build-tools;latest` or `build-tools;34.0.0` or `platforms;android-33`

Comment: I don't understand what's wrong. I updated the question, so you can see what is already installed.

Comment: try like this `sdkmanager --install 'build-tools' 'platform-tools' 'platforms;android-33' 'tools'`

Comment: or simply do `sdkmanager --install 'tools'`

Comment: Both end with error message `Warning: Failed to find package 'build-tools'` or `Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!                         
Warning: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies. `

Comment: do this `sdkmanager --install 'emulator'` and `sdkmanager --install 'tools'`

Comment: `$ sdkmanager --install 'emulator'
Warning: Failed to find package 'emulator'`

Comment: try `--channel=3` or `--channel=0` or `--channel=2` or `--channel=1` with above command line, try `--no_https`

Comment: you can manually download the emulator archive zip file and use `sdkmanager --package_file=package_file`

Comment: if you are behind proxy you need to use `--proxy_host` and `--proxy_port`

Comment: I'm not behind proxy, I installed something, but I can't install `tools`.

Comment: `tools` is obelete use `--include_obsolete`

Comment: `$ sdkmanager --include_obsolete 'tools'
Warning: Dependant package with key emulator not found!                         
Warning: Unable to compute a complete list of dependencies.   `

Comment: `sdkmanager --install 'tools' --include_obsolete` will be the command, but it is only a warning I think it got installed

Comment: There is a warning as well. I will paste to the question my directory structure so far.

Comment: you can install emulator like this `sdkmanager --channel=3 emulator` or `--channel=0` or `--channel=2` or `--channel=1` same applicable while installing tools

Comment: If tools is obsolete, I could use new alternative instead. Where did you find it and what is new alternative?

Comment: i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59907256/653379) and downloaded `sdk-tools-linux.zip`, but don't know where in my directory structure should I unpack it.

Comment: worst case, Try it from android studio, usually the Sdk located in home folder `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` for linux it will be `~/Android/Sdk`