# can i develop app(android) online with coding kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, online-compilation

my pc is old one so it takes a lot of time to process a simple task in android studio
my pc is runing on i5 6th gen
i want to do develop an app on it so is there any website which allows to develop an android app which require coding .
like we have online compiler for c,cpp,python,etc. is there anyting online like that so i can develop an app online using kotlin

i tryed to develop an app on my old pc bit i was not able to do so on android studio

Comment: If you cant use android studio, you can try using Eclipse, which is light weight but requires deep learning curve.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You could take a look at questions like [How to make an Android app without using Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32643297/how-to-make-an-android-app-without-using-android-studio) and whatever relevant you manage to find. Then again an i5 PC isn't that slow, but maybe you have very little RAM(?)