# How do I package Oculus examples for Android?

Tags: android, gradle, apk, oculus

I've downloaded Oculus mobile SDK with some [examples](https://developer3.oculus.com/documentation/mobilesdk/0.4/concepts/mobile-whats-included/). How do I package them into APK? Running `gradlew.bat` from SDK root prints `BUILD SUCCESSFUL`, but generates no APK. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio > Build (menu) > Build APK/Generate Signed APK.

This what you are looking for?

Comment: Is it a way to build projects without IDEs? I just need very minor edits to one of the examples.

Comment: For this question refer to this stackoverflow link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290588/can-i-develop-android-apps-without-an-ide