# Can I build Android apps without Android Studio and Intelij idea and just with netbeans by knowing how to make android apps

Tags: java, android, gradle, netbeans, emulation

I am beginner in Java and I want to build Android apps. Android Studio is installed on my system but will not run, because I have a PC with 2 GB RAM, 32 bit Windows 7 and a 200 GB disk drive.

IntelliJ IDEA didn't work either. I can work with NetBeans. I can't upgrade the RAM, etc. But I am serious on Android app building. Can I install just an emulator and code on NetBeans (XML, Gradle, Java, SDK, etc.) and then run on emulator and finally convert it to APK? If yes, please tell me how to convert to APK, but if not, please advise me to do anything. I appreciate it in advance.

Comment: See also: [Can I develop Android Apps without an IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29290588/can-i-develop-android-apps-without-an-ide)

Comment: Meanwhile a more current answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76150499/19980636

Answer (score 0):

You actually can make Android Apps on Netbeans, but the setup is a bit too complicated. and also emulator will not work on 2 Gb Ram you need 8Gb ram to run emulator